# How to bypass some IP Addresses for Laravel 5 Maintenance Mode

Tags: php, config, laravel-5, maintenance-mode

In Laravel 4 you can bypass some IP addresses for Laravel Maintenance Mode (`php artisan down`) by doing this:

```
App::down(function()
{
    if ( !in_array(Request::getClientIp(), ['192.168.0.1']))
    {
        return Response::view('maintenance', [], 503);
    }
});
```

You can also provide a config file maintenance.php with list of all the ip addresses to allow access to your application when in maintenance mode:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Allowed IP Addresses
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Include an array of IP addresses or ranges that are allowed access to the app when
    | it is in maintenance mode.
    |
    | Supported formats:

    |
    */

    'allowed_ips' => [
        '10.0.2.2',
        '10.2.*.*',
        '10.0.2.3 - 10.0.2.45',
        '10.0.3.0-10.3.3.3'
    ],

];
```

**My question is, How do i achieve this in Laravel 5?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - artisan down / Maintenance Mode except own IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752962/laravel-artisan-down-maintenance-mode-except-own-ip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;



class CheckForMaintenanceMode

{

    protected $request;

    protected $app;



    public function __construct(Application $app, Request $request)

    {

        $this->app = $app;

        $this->request = $request;

    }



    /**

     * Handle an incoming request.

     *

     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request

     * @param  \Closure  $next

     * @return mixed

     */



    public function handle($request, Closure $next)

    {

        if ($this->app->isDownForMaintenance() &&

            !in_array($this->request->getClientIp(), ['::1','another_IP']))

        {

            throw new HttpException(503);

        }



        return $next($request);

    }

}
```

The `'::1'` is your own IP assuming your in localhost, if not the specify your IP. You can excluded multiple IP in the array. check [Excluding your IP Address in Maintenance Mode (php artisan down) in Laravel 5](http://anytch.com/laravel-excluding-ip-address-in-maintenance-mode/)