# How can an admin access the site in maintenance mode with Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use Maintenance Mode, but I don't know how as an administrator can access to my website after that. What should I do?

The goal at the end is to let, for instance, admin go in/out of the maintenance mode using a button or something.

I use this to verify that an admin has actually entered the admin pages.

```
if(Auth::user()->role_id == 1)
```

So how can I exclude from maintenance mode if the user is admin?

Thank you so much..

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752962/laravel-artisan-down-maintenance-mode-except-own-ip/30753279

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace existing middleware `app/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php` with the following content:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Exceptions\MaintenanceModeException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode as Middleware;

class CheckForMaintenanceMode extends Middleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {   
        if (!$this->isAdmin() && $this->app->isDownForMaintenance()) {
            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->app->storagePath() . '/framework/down'), true);

            throw new MaintenanceModeException($data['time'], $data['retry'], $data['message']);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    private function isAdmin()
    {
        return optional(auth()->user())->role_id == 1;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**

`isAdmin()` is the function where the admin user criteria defined. You can change it as per your custom criteria. You can better place this function in the `User` model for reusability.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have activated maintenance mode then system closed even though I am admin.

Comment: What laravel version do you use? Make sure the user is logged in.

Comment: Did it help, @Fazil?

Comment: It worked after a bit of editing for 5.8 thank you so much :)

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that this has to be placed after the SessionMiddilware, otherwise `auth()` won't work.